# Can not start on boot when add more broadcast receive

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I found many topic but no case fit for my question.
The first my app working smooth, it is always startup with device by code bellow:

In AndroidManifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

and receiver:

```
 <!-- start when module start broadcast -->
    <receiver android:name=".StartOnBoot"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- listen messenger received -->
    <receiver
        android:name=".Phone.SmsListener"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And class StartOnBoot

```
public class StartOnBoot  extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        serviceIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(serviceIntent);
    }
} }
```

And now I added 2 broadcast to listen state of SD card and SIM card. But when I finish, My app can not start when my device restarted. And I don't know, where is problem, nothing clue.

```
 <!--        broad cast SDCard receive-->
    <receiver android:name=".Peripheral.SDCardListener">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".Phone.SimCardReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And 2 classes receiver:

```
public class SDCardListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

//restart app when SD card mounted
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("TAG","SDcard state : " + intent.getAction());
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_EJECT)){
       //sdcard eject
    }else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
        SDCard.getInstance().SDCardMounted();
     }
   }
  }
```

for sim state:

```
public class SimCardReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("TAG", "Sim state :" + intent.getAction());
   }
  }
```

My device target is only Android 7.1, SDK lv 25.
Some methods I tried but not work:

- I removed SimCardReceiver
- I added "android:priortity to StartBoot" like this:

> <intent-filter **android:priority="1000"**>

But still not working, Remember, my app always work without 2 broadcast SDCardListener and SimCardReceiver
Extra question:

- How many broadcast are available to use in one app. How many is good ? one or not limit
- Could I merge all receiver to one broadcast

Comment: Technically, there's no problem having all of those Receivers. If I'm following the description correctly, my first guess would be that one of them is crashing before `StartOnBoot` runs. You might check your logs for any relevant info, and/or add some breakpoints or `try`-`catch`es in the Receivers, etc. Probably the first thing I'd do is to temporarily remove all of your code from the suspect Receivers, leaving just empty `onReceive()` methods. If `StartOnBoot` runs like that, then the issue is likely in the removed code. Otherwise, if it still fails, then it's possibly the overall setup.

Comment: @MikeM. thank you. Your cmt is  helpful so I already fixed it. but I didn't understand yet that why . I removed one in two action then it is work smothly '<action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />'. I will try find the exact reason later.